# Conteúdo de Texto para Link de Migração

Tags: bug, status-recusado, tradução

O texto que aparece ao migrarmos uma questão no site entre Meta e SOPT

Está parcialmente traduzido, como por exemplo, nessa pergunta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa mesma frase já foi reportada em outros lugares. Então eu tenho a impressão que é uma string padrão contida no banco de dados que representa a atividade do site (o público alvo) que ainda não foi traduzida. Não conheço a arquitetura do software mas se está bem feito, uma mudança solucionará todos os problemas.

Comment: @bigown, sugeres fechamento da questão?

Comment: Acho que não precisa, deixa o problema mais claro.

Answer (score 1):

The site description tag has now been updated, but this doesn't apply to questions already migrated or coming from other English site. At the moment we don't have a different site description for each site translated in every language we support.

Comment: Any chance to show the site name instead of the description? That would make more sense when the languages mix.

Comment: @bfavaretto this should be a feature-request on meta.so

Comment: Thanks, but I'll leave it alone until we know if migrating from the original SO is something that will happen often. If it's not, this is too minor to justify changing.